# SASI Index is node level or cluster level?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

Can anyone tell if we are creating SASI index then it will create index on node level or cluster level. How SASI different with normal Secondary Index? Is it worth to use or not?

However, I went through the documentation but did understand much about pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

When I studied the document found "SSTable attached secondary indexes (SASI) can be created on a non-collection column defined in a table" so it should be distibuted across the cluster.